# Calculating an Age Range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a report that only shows clients that are age 65 years and up. I'm wondering what the SQL equivalent of months_between is and also how to correctly limit the report to clients 65+ years-old. I've included my statement below. Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

```
 SELECT person.idFamily AS Family_ID, person.id AS Person_ID,(SELECT person.firstName+ ', ' + person.lastName) AS Name, person.Race AS Race, person.Ethnicity as Ethnicity, family.capidCounty AS County, Person.BirthDate AS [DateofBirth], trunc(months_between(sysdate,DateofBirth)/12))AS Age
FROM Family
LEFT JOIN person ON family.Id = person.idFamily
```

Comment: Tag properly!!!  Since when SQL Server has `months_between()` and `sysdate`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for getting people older than 65 years and their age. DATEDIFF calculates the difference between two dates and DATEADD can add/subtract from dates.

```
select *, DATEDIFF(year,BirthDate,getdate()) as Age from Person where BirthDate < DATEADD(year, -65, getdate())
```

More about [DATEDIFF](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp) and [DATEADD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Well something like this should work in SQL Server:

```
SELECT p.idFamily AS Family_ID, p.id AS Person_ID,
       (p.firstName + ', ' + p.lastName) AS Name, p.Race AS Race, p.Ethnicity as Ethnicity,
       f.capidCounty AS County, p.BirthDate AS [DateofBirth], 
       datediff(month, dateofbirth, getdate()) / 12 as age
FROM Family f LEFT JOIN
     person p
     ON f.Id = p.idFamily;
```

This is not an exact match, but the logic is probably good enough.  Note that the age will increment on the first of the month of the month with the birthday.